# Unable to create cloud function in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hi I am trying to create a GCP Cloud function using python 3.7. This is the default function which comes pre-populated in the text editor when you try and create a cloud function. However, when I try to create it I get this very strange error.

[image]

I am not using the default service account. I have created a separate cloud function service account which I am using which is part of the "Cloud Functions Invoker" role in GCP IAM.

Comment: Can u provide a glimpse of your logs.. Maybe that could clear the doubt a little bit.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult for us to help you identify the root cause of the error since the message only states to retry later due to an internal error. However, the [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans) team should be able to use the number you are given to identify the error and provide you with appropriate advice.

Hope you find this useful!